# How to specify which python to use when writing vim script in python

Tags: python, vim

I started to learn how to write vim script in python.

I come across of this tutorial

https://dzone.com/articles/how-write-vim-plugins-python

and my first vim script looks like the following

```
function! Reddit()

python << EOF
import sys
print sys.executable
print "hello Reddit"
EOF

endfunction
```

as you can see, the `print sys.executable` prints out the python on the system path.

As I use pyenv a lot, how can I set vim to recognize my python according to my working environment?

Comment: You can't.  Vim always uses its compiled-in Python interpreter.

Comment: @SatoKatsura In newer Vim versions there's [`'pythondll'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27pythondll%27) which can be used. This was added in [7.4.907](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/d94464ee294a351ce7b6ba18e8bd3f24f1bef920).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker, how can I set it on mac or for neovim?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Sure, but that has nothing to do with `pyenv` (or `virtualenv`, for that matter).  It doesn't enable the internal interpreter to switch to non-default environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don’t mind using Neovim instead of vim, you would be able to select which Python interpreter to use via:

```
let g:python_host_prog = '/path/to/your/interpreter/python'
let g:python3_host_prog = '/path/to/your/interpreter/python3'
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, I am using neovim.